# Android ADT: No fragment_main.xml, only activity_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sdk, fragment

I'm trying to learn how to program android applications, so I downloaded the ADT bundle that google supplied, and I tried following the tutorial that allowed me to create a simple application. However, during the procedures, there are several instructions telling me to open up the fragment_main.xml file, but my layout/res/ directory did not have this file, only the activity_main.xml file. Furthermore, when creating new Android activities, there was never an option to name my fragment layout, indicating that eclipse just doesn't create it for some reason. I didn't think this would be an issue at first (I just edited activity_main instead), until I realized that the tutorial wanted us to use the some information from the fragment class or xml file.

Does anyone know why my Eclipse IDE is not creating a fragment_main.xml? I will try to supply more details if necessary.

Comment: You will have to provide the versions being used (eclipse, bundle and OS) to be able to answer. Also refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67421

Comment: The issues that were presented on that link are exactly the issues that I have right now. Currently upgrading to 22.6.1 right now, and I'll tell you how it goes.

Comment: Good to see that your issue is solved. Usually, you dont mark it solved, you choose one of the responses as answer, for Stackoverflow to track.

Comment: What if none of the answers were the correct ones, but prabindh's comment was the right one?

Comment: Since I wasnt sure of the versions, I provided it as a comment. I will make it as an answer and then your issue is solved, mark it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the versions you indicated in the comment response, I think updating to the later versions (22.6+) would help, as discussed in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67421

Answer (score 5):

While creating the new Android Project in one of the panels select "Blank activity with Fragment" instead of default selection "Blank Activity". The Android Developer tutorial does not say anything about it. Doing so will create the file fragment_main.xml in res/layout/ which is needed to continue subsequent steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new project with "Blank Activity with Fragment". I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Open MainActivity.java  from the src/(package name file)/ directory. Then inside the java file there is a method called OnCreate() that has setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) as default.

Change that to R.layout.activity_main to R.layout.fragment_main 
so instead of having 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
you'll have 
setContentView(R.layout.fragment.main)

Once that's done change the name of the activity_main.xml file under the /res/layout/ directory to fragment_main.xml

Thanks for that Onik!